# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm setting a many to many relationship, my join table JoinTable has a composite Pk with two keys, the problem is that when I try to persist my entity hibernate keeps saying that he can't convert `java.lang.Long` to the required type (`User` or `Weeks`)

I've tried changing the attributes to java primitives (long and int, respectively) but then hibernate can't set this values to the target type (an object).

I've mapped the relation like this:

**User.java**

```java
@Column(name="id", nullable=false)  
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="USER_ID_GENERATOR")  
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="USER_ID_GENERATOR", strategy="native")    
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", targetEntity=com.ti.project.Model.JoinTable.class)  @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK}) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)  
private java.util.Set jointable = new java.util.HashSet();
```

**Weeks.java**

```java
@Column(name="week_id", nullable=false) 
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="WEEK_ID_GENERATOR")  
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="WEEK_ID_GENERATOR", strategy="native")    
private int week_id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="week",targetEntity=com.ti.project.Model.JoinTable.class)   
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK}) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)  
private java.util.Set jointable = new java.util.HashSet();
```

**JoinTable.java**

```java
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn       
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=com.ti.project.Model.User.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)  
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK})    
@JoinColumns(value={ @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) }, foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FKuser_su465470"))  
private com.ti.project.Model.User user;

@Column(name="user_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)  
@Id     
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="USERID_GENERATOR", strategy="foreign", parameters=@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name="property", value="user"))    
private long userId;

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn   
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=com.ti.project.Model.Weeks.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK})    
@JoinColumns(value={ @JoinColumn(name="week_id", referencedColumnName="week_id", nullable=false) }, foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FKweek_su338979")) 
private com.ti.project.Model.Weeks week;

@Column(name="week_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)  
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="WEEKID_GENERATOR")   
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="WEEKID_GENERATOR", strategy="foreign", parameters=@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name="property", value="week"))    
private int weekId;
```

**JoinTablePK.java**

```java
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=com.ti.project.Model.User.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)  
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK})    
@JoinColumns(value={ @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) }, foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FKuser_su465470"))  
private com.ti.project.Model.User user;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=com.ti.project.Model.Weeks.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK})    
@JoinColumns(value={ @JoinColumn(name="week_id", referencedColumnName="week_id", nullable=false) }, foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FKweek_su338979")) 
private com.ti.project.Model.Weeks week;
```

And this is the exception generated:

```java
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'com.ti.project.Model.Weeks' for property 'week'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'com.ti.project.Model.Weeks' for property 'week': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I expect to persist this `JoinTable` entity, but this exception is making me crazy Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Your mapping is all wrong.
You have @OneToMany and @ManyToOne mapping. Why are you using a middle table ? You will only need a middle table in @ManyToMany relationships.
Remove the JoinTable.class because isn't referenced in your code.

Another problem is your targetClass.
Look how to mapping a @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationship. It must to be easy.

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Thiago, thanks for the response. Actually it's a @ManyToMany that's the reason for the middle table, user and week in JoinTable are a composite PK, and also FKs from User and Week tables.